# Cannot invoke 'findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '(([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void)'

Tags: ios, swift, syntax-error

I'm following a tutorial called `How to Build a Simple iOS Chat App` on Youtube which made by a channel called `Code With Chris`. I followed all his type and I got the following error in Xcode:

```
/Users/David/Documents/360Drive/Xcode/Try/Learn With Chris/ChatApp/ChatApp/ChatApp/ViewController.swift:53:15: Cannot invoke 'findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '(([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void)'
```

Here's my code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ChatApp
//
//  Created by David Chen on 15/4/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 cwsoft. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var messagesArray:[String] = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var MessageTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ButtonSend: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var DockViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var MessageTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Set delegate
        self.MessageTableView.delegate = self
        self.MessageTableView.dataSource = self
        self.MessageTextField.delegate = self

        let tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tableViewTapped")
        self.MessageTableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        self.messagesArray.append("Test 1")
        self.messagesArray.append("Test 2")
        self.messagesArray.append("Test 3")
    }

    @IBAction func ButtonSendPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        self.MessageTextField.endEditing(true)

        var newMessageObject:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Message")
        newMessageObject["Text"] = self.MessageTextField.text
        newMessageObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success == true) {
                NSLog("Success")
            } else {
                NSLog("Error")
            }
        }
    }

    func retrieveMessages() {
        var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (object: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            self.messagesArray = [String]()
            for messageObject in objects {
                let messageText:String? = (messageObject as PFObject)["Text"] as? String
                if messagetext != nil {
                    self.messagesArray.append(messageText!)
                }
            }
        }
        self.MessageTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableViewTapped() {
        self.MessageTextField.endEditing(true)
    }

    //MARK : TextField Delegage Methods

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.DockViewHeightConstraint.constant = 320
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.DockViewHeightConstraint.constant = 60
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
    }

    //MARK : Table View Delegate Methods

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.MessageTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.messagesArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messagesArray.count
    }
}
```

Here's the link of the tutorial
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVItNKOITxg&list=PLMRqhzcHGw1b2gX4gn5B3ILqiEF-UYei5)

Thanks for any helpful suggestions :)

Answer (score -1):

There have been many changes with the last xCode update. I can not really explain why exactly some changes need to be done. You better read the changeLogs! So will I later on :)
In the meantime try this:

```
func retrieveMessages() {
    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object, error) -> Void in
        self.messagesArray = [String]()
        for messageObject in object! {
            let messageText:String? = (messageObject as! PFObject)["Text"] as? String
            if messageText != nil {
                self.messagesArray.append(messageText!)
            }
        }
    }
    self.MessageTableView.reloadData()
}
```

It seems that in some cases you don't need to specify the type anymore. In other cases you need to though. In this case, there is no need but you need unwrap your object array.

Comment: /Users/David/Documents/360Drive/Xcode/Try/Learn With Chris/ChatApp/ChatApp/ChatApp/ViewController.swift:56:34: Use of unresolved identifier 'objects'

Comment: on line 'for messageObject in objects {'

Comment: change objects to object or copy my whole comment. And explain the donvote please, as mistakes in copy-and-paste are not my fault^^ ;)

Comment: I copied all the code in your comment and got that message. @Akanio

Comment: The line your are talking about is not mentioned in my comment tho. Please copy and paste it again. And of course you need to replace your own function...

Comment: I replaced the func in your comment and get that error, sir.... It says "Use of unresolved identifier 'objects'"

Comment: Please check again. My comment doesn't have 'objects' anywhere. it's object!.

Comment: Correct! removing the type from object and error works